# Como obtener el Maximo, Max de un DataTable de Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net

tengo un sistema en visual basic .NET, todo el dia he tratado de recuperar dos valores o una fila, mi problema radica que este sistema esta con dataset, este tiene un (datatable, bindingsurce), pero no he podido aplicar correctamente el codigo que me facilito un.

```
Dim acvalormaximo = From aoRow As DataRowView In mMstbenBndSrc
                                Where CType(aoRow.Row,dsConfBanco.MSTBENRow).IDECIA = _oClsFstData.IDECIA 
Select ("CODBEN").Max()
```

Espero sus comentario o me indiquen mi errro

saludps

Answer (score 0):

No me aclaro con tu código, pero para un `DataTable` tienes el método `Compute()` con el que conseguirás lo que buscas.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
Dim maximo as integer = DataTable.Compute("MAX(Campo)", "")
Dim minmo as integer = Dataset.tables(0).Compute("MIN(Campo)", "")
Dim AnyoActual as String = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, now()).ToString
Dim maximoAnyo as integer = DataTable.Compute("MAX(Campo)", "Anyo='" & AnyoActual & "'")
```

Comment: Uso dataset, trate de implementar ese codigo anteriormente, medio error, quise hacer un LINQ

Comment: Uso dataset, trate de implementar ese codigo anteriormente, medio error, trato de hacerlo con LINQ, tratare de limpiar el codigo,**negrita**
dim acvalor maximo = from aoRow in DataRowView in mBindinSourceCodigo
where Ctype(aoRow.row, datasetbanco.mstcodigorow).idecia = codigo.idecia
select ("CODBEN").max()**negrita**
Saludos don roger